# IE 11 Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'replace'

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-11

My jquery script, which otherwise works, throws an error in IE11:

Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'replace'

Can anyone tell me why?

Basically, the script just shows/hides divs and other content. It does this  based on whether or not the link used to get to the page has a particular query string.

To see the error (and the code), just open the following link in IE11. (Script debugging has to be turned on.)

https://jsfiddle.net/rpt613/dp2kcL7v/

The code...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var url = window.location.href
option = url.search(/[?]option=/gi);
    if (option != -1) {
        showContent();
        changeStyle();
        removeShowLink();
    } else {
        $('div.backToTaskList, div.spacer, div.backLink').css('display' ==
        'none');
    }
    });

function showContent() {
    $('.backToTaskList, div.spacer').hide();
    $('span.toggleTaskList').hide();
    $('#RelatedTopics').hide();
}

function removeShowLink() {
        $("body").each(function() {
            if ($(this).prop("id") == 'allTask') {
                $('div.backToTaskList:contains("Show More")').each(
                    function() {
                        $(this).html($(this).html().split(
                            "Show More").join(""));
                        $("span#pipe").remove();
                    });
            }
        });
    }
    /* Restyle h2 to match styling of h1*/

function changeStyle() {
    $("h2.programmingtask").css({
        "color": "#199bd8",
        "font-weight": "normal",
        "font-style": "normal",
        "font-size": "14pt",
        "font-family": "Verdana",
        "margin-top": "45px"
    });
    /* Replace text content of h2 element with its ID attribute*/
    var replaceWith = $("h2.programmingtask, h1.programmingtask").attr('id');
    $("h2.programmingtask, h1.programmingtask").text(replaceWith);
}
```

Comment: I don't see the replace method being used in your code. Am i missing something ?

Comment: Note that some of the code makes very little sense, for instance iterating over `body` just to check if it has an ID ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's this line

```
$('div.backToTaskList, div.spacer, div.backLink').css('display' == 'none');
```

it should be

```
$('div.backToTaskList, div.spacer, div.backLink').css('display', 'none');
```

and that's an error in any browser, as jQuery tries to use `string.replace` on the arguments passed in `css()` and instead only receives a boolean.

Comment: How could I have missed that?!  I'm a happy camper now. Thanks Adeneo.

Comment: It's solve the asker problem but not solve the question title.

Comment: @LeonanCarvalho . it solves both. The error message in the title comes from jQuery's internal code where `css(Boolean)` doesn't work, simply because `true.replace('string', 'string')` is invalid.